# Notepad++ remove all text except 8 character string containing digits

Tags: regex, notepad++

I received a text file from a third part that contains ID's that I need to strip out.  The file also contains a lot of other data that I don't need however and is not in delimited or fixed width format. So I was wondering if there was a way to use Notepad++ and regex to remove everything except my ID numbers?  The format of the ID numbers is that they are 8 digits long and must start with a 0.

Examples:00000213, 00023234, 02456343

Comment: What's with longer numbers. Should they be deleted, or do you want to keep 8 of its digits?

Comment: Any longer number can be deleted as well...they must be only 8 characters of digits long.

Comment: Are you familiar with using regexes in find-and-replace in N++? I assumed you are, but I can quickly go over that as well if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers you want to keep, can be matched like this:

```
(?<!\d)0\d{7}(?!\d)
```

Where the [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) make sure that you get exactly 8 digits and not more.

Now you can simply match all other characters, until you reach one of these numbers, and delete everything else. In addition, you need to consider the case that you are removing the characters *after* the last of those numbers, up to the end of the string:

```
.*?((?<!\d)0\d{7}(?!\d)|\Z)
```

And replace with `$1\t` to write back the number that you don't want to delete and a tab after it, so that you can still distinguish them after everything else has been removed (thanks to Sniffer for the latter suggestion). The `?` at the beginning is important so that you match as little as possible (and don't pass the first number if there is another one coming later). Make sure to activate the `dot matches newline` option. And also make sure to update Notepad++ to version 6.

Comment: Pretty clever idea that deserves +1, one note, he should replace with `$1\t` just to keep tabs between the found numbers so he can isolate them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `\D` with `[ ]` to remove non-digit text
2. Replace `[ ]+` with `[ ]` to collapse the extra spaces. Now you have every string of consecutive digits, separated by spaces.
3. Replace `[ ]([^0]\d+|\d{1,7}|\d{8}\d+)[ ]` with `[ ]` to remove numbers that don't start with 0, are 1-7 characters long, or are more than 8 characters long.

You can use any delimiter you want; it doesn't have to be `[ ]`. It can be `,`, `w`, `☺`, basically anything other than a digit will work.

Note: Spaces are written as `[ ]` for clarity, but it's not necessary.